# Object reference not set to an instancet - variable has value still error is coming

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I am getting error like Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

But while debugging I see value is coming perfectly in variable, so any idea why still this error is coming.

please see below image and below code also.

```
var vipAppointmentType = await _codeTypeRepository.GetCodeSetsAsQueryable()
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == entity.VIPTypeId);

var dto = ViewVipAppointmentTypeDto.Create(
          entity.Id,
          entity.Code,
          entity.Description,
          vipAppointmentType.Name,
          entity.IsFreeMembership);

dto.VipType.Id = vipAppointmentType.Id;
dto.VipType.Name = vipAppointmentType.Name;
dto.VipType.AbbreviationCode = vipAppointmentType.AbbreviationCode;
```

Comment: Check the `dto` for `null`.

Comment: Perhaps you need to set dto.VipType = new VipType().

Comment: most likely cause is `dto.VipType` is a class of type `VipType` and it is not initialized. Initializing a parent class does not instantiate property classes automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `dto.VipType` is null. Initialize VipType as follows:

```
dto.VipType=new VipType(); // add this line
dto.VipType.Id = vipAppointmentType.Id;
dto.VipType.Name = vipAppointmentType.Name;
dto.VipType.AbbreviationCode = vipAppointmentType.AbbreviationCode;
```